# Adding factor versions of variables with within function

Tags: r

The specific instruction I have are "Create stateFac and typeFac, the factor versions of state and type, and add them to aaup2. Use the within() function to avoid the aaup2$ prefix"

aaup2 is the name of the dataframe used and state and type are varibles.

```
states2 <- aaup2[, 3]
types2 <- aaup2[, 4]
within(aaup2, {
 stateFac <- factor(states2)
 typeFac <- factor(types2)
})
```

This is what I have done and it does add the new factor versions to aaup2 but if I run aaup2 again stateFac and typeFac are not there. Am I missing something that would permanently add them to aaup2?

Comment: You need to assign back to same object i..e `aaup2 <- within(aaup2, ...`

Comment: Thank you can't believe I missed that